# Why segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers

Following block of code is giving segmentation fault.Please help.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
        int testcase,num;
        int i,j,*array;
        scanf("%d",&testcase);
        for(i=0;i<testcase;i++){
            scanf("%d",&num);
            for(j=0;j<num;j++){
                scanf("%d",(array+j));
            }
        }
        i=0;
        for(i=0;*(array+i)!='\0';i++){
            printf("%d",1);
        }
        }
```

Comment: Because `scanf("%d",(array+j));` invokes **undefined behavior**. `array` is an indeterminate pointer. The for-loop at the end is equally invalid.

Comment: Where does it segfault, and why havent you stepped through in a debugger?

Comment: But this segment doesn't gives Segmentation fault

Comment: It could wash your car and paint your house. It could do nothing. **It's *undefined* behavior.** Consider this: `int a;` Now, what is the value of `a`? You don't know? That's because *you can't know*. It's indeterminate. Worse, `int a; int b=a;` What is the value of `b`? Again, you don't know. Even *evaluating* `a` as a value is undefined behavior. So it also goes with that pointer in your code.

Comment: @Johnsmith Then perhaps you could indicate which line does segfault?

Comment: @Johnsmith regardless of what line the fault appears at, it's root cause is the writing of invalid memory (which is what your `scanf("%d",(array+j))` is doing in this case). That _could_ cause an immediate fault, or it _could_ just corrupt memory that will lead to a fault later, or it _could_ corrupt memory and never even be noticed.... _undefined_: what will happen is not defined (and not guaranteed to be consistent either).

Answer (score 5):

**Edit 2**

Wanted to put this on top.

I just noticed that your code is kind of weird. When you're reading the numbers, you have a loop over `i`, but then another loop over `j` inside - and each iteration you just overwrite the values you already read. This is weird, and I'm not sure what your original intent was. So although the `segmentation fault` is still caused because of unallocated array, the solution I wrote here isn't the correct one (and I'm not sure what would be the correct solution until I understand what you meant to do)

**end of Edit2**

`array` is uninitialized.

It's a pointer pointing to a place in memory, but that place isn't free, So when you write there you write over important stuff and cause segmentation fault.

The best way to solve it in your case is to add

```
array=malloc(sizeof(int)*testcase);
```

just after the line where you read `testcase`, so just after

```
scanf("%d",&testcase);
```

Also, if you do that, it's good practice to `free` that memory once you're done using it. So in your case add

```
free(array);
```

just after you're done printing the whole array

**Edit** Just noticed you have another bug - at the loop where you're printing the array:

```
for(i=0;*(array+i)!='\0';i++){
```

That is bad, bacause you're treating `array`, which is an array of ints, like it's a string. "normal" arrays don't end in `'\0'`. Moreover - `'\0'` is a `char`, and `*(array+i)` is an `int`.

Replace that line with

```
for (i=0;i<testcase;i++){
```

Comment: Don't forget to free memory you dynamically allocate.

Comment: Technically `'\0'` *is* an `int` (character literals are `int`s), but the assumption that the array must end with a `0` of course stays invalid.