# Segmentation Fault While Sorting

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have implemented quick-sort.But this code is giving me segmentation fault.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void Quick_Sort(int *a,int p,int r);
int partition(int *a,int p,int r);
int main(){
    int testcase,num,search;
    int i,j,*array;
    scanf("%d",&testcase);
    for(i=0;i<testcase;i++){
        scanf("%d",&num);
        array=malloc(sizeof(int)*num);
        for(j=0;j<num;j++){
            scanf("%d",(array+j));
        }
        Quick_Sort(array,0,num-1);
        scanf("%d",&search);
        /*for(j=0;j<num;j++){
            if(search==*(array+j)){
                printf("%d\n",j+1 );
                break;
            }

        }*/
    }
    for(i=0;*(array+i)!='\0';++i){
        printf("%d ",*(array+i));
    }
}
void Quick_Sort(int *a,int p,int r){
    int q;
    if(p<r){
        q=partition(a,p,r);
        Quick_Sort(a,p,q);
        Quick_Sort(a,q+1,r);
    }
}
int partition(int *a,int p,int r){
    int i,j,x,temp;
    i=p-1;
    j=r+1;
    x=*(a+p);
    while(1){
        do{
        j=j-1;
    }
    while(x<=(*(a+j)));

    do{
        i=i+1;
    }
    while(x>=(*(a+i)));

    if(i<j){
        temp=*(a+i);
        *(a+i)=*(a+j);
        *(a+j)=temp;
    }else{
        return j;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe it was pointed out in an answer to a previous question of yours that `*(array + i) != '\0'` doesn't work for arrays of `int`s.

Comment: The printing loop seems to assume that the array is 0-terminated, does an out-of-bounds access to check it, and which it anyhow certainly won't be (and which seems fantastically weird for an array of integers).

Comment: @Kninnug:Then what should i write

Comment: As pointed out [in said answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19725461/249237): `i < testcase`. It's generally a good idea to fix *all* the errors an answer points out before asking another question.

Comment: @Kninnug:That was wrong.

Comment: Ah, I see, it should be `i < num`. There are, of course many more errors. And, why don't you use array-subscripts for accesing elements? All those `*(array+i)` over the place just make it harder to read. `array[i]` is much clearer.

Comment: @Kninnug:Using them because of advantage.

Comment: There is no advantage, they are exactly the same. (C99 §6.5.2.1 par 2: "The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2))).")

Comment: First write clear code (1); next write working code (2); only then consider writing optimal code (3). Your `*(a+i)` is an example of putting (3) before (1) and (2). Also - how are some of your `while(); do{}while();` loops meant to work?

Comment: @Kninnug: `*(array + ) != '\0'` is completely legitimate; `'\0'` is an integer constant (this is C, not C++).  It is a weird and pointless way of writing `array[i] != 0`, but it is valid and absolutely _does_ work for arrays of `int`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - but only if you `calloc` the array to be one larger than `num`... otherwise you did not create a valid "end of array". And it will surely fail if the array to be sorted contains the number zero.

Comment: @Floris: It depends on the larger context. On its own, `*(array + i) != '\0'` is fine as a condition to check whether the contents of an array element are non-zero.  However, in the larger context of `for (i = 0; *(array + i) != '\0'; i++)` as a way of detecting the span of an array, it is at best error prone compared to the obvious `for (i = 0; i < num; i++)` where `num` is the number of elements in the array. You'd have a slightly unusual array if you can guarantee that a zero value marks the end. I stand by my comment that `*(array + i) != '\0'` is a peculiar way of writing `array[i] != 0`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I didn't mean to say it wasn't legal or valid C, just that it does not do what he seems to think it does. If there isn't a `0` at the end of the array then this will invoke undefined behaviour. Anyway, when I run this code it segfaults before this loop is encountered (in `partition` at the line `while(x<=(*(a+j)));`).

Comment: @Kninnug: I see now what you meant.  Taken in isolation, your comment seemed to mean that it wasn't legal C.  Given the context, I agree that it is the wrong way to be testing for the end of the array.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I have no issue with the legality - just that it doesn't make sense. There is a lot in this code that doesn't make sense. I started trying to fix it but gave up. "this mess is so big and so deep and so tall"... (apologies to Dr Seuss).

Comment: @Floris (and Kninnug): C J Date likes to invoke the "Incoherency Principle": _It is difficult to criticize coherently that which is incoherent to start with._  There's a large element of 'that applies here'.

Answer (score 2):

#### Reading the data

Your data file seems to be structured as:

```
T
N1 V11 V12 V13 ... V1N S1
N2 V21 V22 V23 ... V2N S2
...
```

You have a total number of test cases, T.  Then for each test case, you have a number of entries in the array (N1, N2, etc), each time followed by the appropriate number of values, V<sub>1</sub>1 .. V<sub>1</sub>N, and a spare value which you're supposed to search for (all described using 1-based array notations; in C, you'll be using 0-based arrays).  Although I've shown the data for each test set all on a single line, the actual data file could have the numbers laid out in any sequence — everything could be on one line, or each number on a line of its own possibly with blank lines separating them, or any mixture of these formats.

The `main()` program you show does not do a particularly good job of reading that data. It lacks all error checking.  It uses the (legal but) bizarre `*(array + i)` notations instead of the simpler to understand `array[i]` notation, apparently in the belief that it will be more efficient.  When you use pointers for efficiency, you don't keep on adding `i` to the value before dereferencing the pointer. Your code dynamically allocates memory but never frees it, leaking horribly.

#### Reading the data using subscript notation

In this revised code, I'm using `return 1;` to exit from the program.  It should print an error message too, but I'm moderately lazy.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int testcase, num, search;
    int i, j, *array;
    if (scanf("%d", &testcase) != 1)
        return 1;

    for (i = 0; i < testcase; i++)
    {
        if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1)
            return 1;
        array = malloc(sizeof(int)*num);
        if (array == 0)
            return 1;
        for (j = 0; j < num; j++)
        {
            if (scanf("%d", &array[j]) != 1)
                return 1;
        }
        //Quick_Sort(array, 0, num-1);
        if (scanf("%d", &search) != 1)
            return 1;
        for (j = 0; j < num; j++)
        {
            if (search == array[j])
            {
                printf("%d\n", j+1);
                break;
            }
        }
        // Print the array - best encapsulated in a small function
        for (j = 0; j < num; j++)
        {
            printf(" %d", array[j]);
            if (j % 10 == 9)
                putchar('\n');
        }
        if (j % 10 != 0)
            putchar('\n');
        // Prevent memory leaks
        free(array);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I note in passing that the search loop will work whether or not the QuickSort sorts the data; it makes no use of the fact that the array is sorted. You could print the data before the sort and after the sort.  You should tag the output to identify what you're printing.  For example, the search code might write:

```
printf("Found %d at %d\n", search, j);
```

You also do not identify when the value being searched for is not found.

It is also often a good idea to print the data you read after you've read it and before you process it, just to make sure that your program is getting the data you expect it to get.  It can lead to confusion if the program isn't working on the data you think it is working on.

Note that this code does not make any assumptions about the values in the arrays beyond 'they are valid integers'.  And it does check every input operation.  Tedious though it may seem, it is necessary to head off trouble.

#### Reading the data using pointer notation

Here is code making more or less idiomatic use of pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int testcase;
    if (scanf("%d", &testcase) != 1)
        return 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < testcase; i++)
    {
        int num;
        if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1)
            return 1;
        int *array = malloc(sizeof(int)*num);
        if (array == 0)
            return 1;
        int *end = array + num;
        int *ptr;
        for (ptr = array; ptr < end; ptr++) 
        {
            if (scanf("%d", ptr) != 1)
                return 1;
        }

        //Quick_Sort(array, 0, num-1);

        int search;
        if (scanf("%d", &search) != 1)
            return 1;
        for (ptr = array; ptr < end; ptr++) 
        {
            if (search == *ptr)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (ptr < end)
            printf("Found %d at %td\n", search, ptr - array + 1);
        else
            printf("Missing %d\n", search);

        // Print the array - best encapsulated in a small function
        printf("Array (%d):", num);
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < num; j++)
        {
            printf(" %d", array[j]);
            if (j % 10 == 9)
                putchar('\n');
        }
        if (j % 10 != 0)
            putchar('\n');

        // Prevent memory leaks
        free(array);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The printing loop is simplest if written using indexing, so I didn't change it to use pointers.  It could be done, but using `(ptr - array)` instead of `j` in the 'is it time to print a newline' code makes it less worthwhile.  The code uses C99 features like declaring variables as they're needed and the `t` qualifier in `%td` for the `ptrdiff_t` value.  It could be written to use a VLA instead of `malloc()`, too.

#### Sample input data

```
3
2 1 2 1
3 3 2 0 1
4 5 4 3 2 4
```

#### Sample output

```
Found 1 at 1
Array (2): 1 2
Missing 1
Array (3): 3 2 0
Found 4 at 2
Array (4): 5 4 3 2
```

#### Working Quicksort Code

Your partition algorithm was defective.  It is fixed, with key changes marked.  The debugging scaffolding that I used while sorting out the issues is left in place, with many of the printing operations that guided me commented out.  Read [Programming Pearls](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201657880) by Jon Bentley, especially 'Column 11: Sorting' (chapter 11, but the chapters were originally columns in the Communications of the ACM, hence the designation Column 11).  It was an invaluable guide while fixing the problems.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void Quick_Sort(int *a, int p, int r);
static int  partition(int *a, int p, int r);

static void dump_partition(char const *tag, int const *data, int lo, int hi);

/* Debugging functions */
static void check_sorted(int const *data, int lo, int hi);
static int *copy_partition(int const *data, int lo, int hi);
static void check_consistency(int const *a1, int const *a2, int lo, int hi);

int main(void)
{
    int testcase, num, search;
    int i, j, *array;
    if (scanf("%d", &testcase) != 1)
        return 1;

    for (i = 0; i < testcase; i++)
    {
        if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1)
            return 1;
        array = malloc(sizeof(int)*num);
        if (array == 0)
            return 1;
        for (j = 0; j < num; j++)
        {
            if (scanf("%d", &array[j]) != 1)
                return 1;
        }

        printf("\nData set %d:\n", i);
        int *copy = copy_partition(array, 0, num-1);
        dump_partition("Before:", array, 0, num-1);
        //dump_partition("Copy", copy, 0, num-1);
        Quick_Sort(array, 0, num-1);
        dump_partition("After: ", array, 0, num-1);
        check_sorted(array, 0, num-1);
        check_consistency(array, copy, 0, num-1);
        free(copy);

        if (scanf("%d", &search) != 1)
            return 1;
        for (j = 0; j < num; j++)
        {
            if (search == array[j])
                break;
        }
        if (j < num && search == array[j])
            printf("Found %d at %d\n", search, j+1);
        else
            printf("Missing %d\n", search);

        // Prevent memory leaks
        free(array);
    }
    return 0;
}

/* Although we're interested in data[lo]..data[hi], the copy must have data[0]..data[lo-1] too */
static int *copy_partition(int const *data, int lo, int hi)
{
    assert(lo <= hi);
    size_t nbytes = (hi + 1) * sizeof(int);
    int *space = (int *)malloc(nbytes);
    if (space == 0)
    {
        fputs("Out of memory\n", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
    memmove(space, data, nbytes);
    return(space);
}

/* Check that the two arrays contain the same sets of data */
/* Each value in a1 must be present in a2 and vice versa */
static void check_consistency(int const *a1, int const *a2, int lo, int hi)
{
    int *a3 = copy_partition(a1, lo, hi);
    int  a3_lo = lo;
    int  a3_hi = hi;
    //printf("-->> check_consistency:\n");
    //dump_partition("a1", a1, lo, hi);
    //dump_partition("a2", a2, lo, hi);
    //dump_partition("a3", a3, lo, hi);
    for (int i = lo; i <= hi; i++)
    {
        int found = 0;
        for (int j = a3_lo; j <= a3_hi; j++)
        {
            if (a2[i] == a3[j])
            {
                /* Found a match for a2[i] at a3[j] */
                /* Move a3[j] to end of array and ignore it from here on */
                //printf("Found a2[%d] = %d at a3[%d] = %d\n", i, a2[i], j, a3[j]);
                int t = a3[a3_hi];
                a3[a3_hi] = a3[j];
                a3[j] = t;
                a3_hi--;
                //dump_partition("a3-free", a3, a3_lo, a3_hi);
                //dump_partition("a3-used", a3, a3_hi+1, hi);
                found = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            printf("No value %d for a2[%d] in a1\n", a2[i], i);
            dump_partition("a2", a2, lo, hi);
            dump_partition("a1-free", a3, a3_lo, a3_hi);
            dump_partition("a1-used", a3, a3_hi+1, hi);
        }
    }
    free(a3);
    //printf("<<-- check_consistency\n");
}

static void dump_partition(char const *tag, int const *data, int lo, int hi)
{
    printf("%s [%d..%d]%s", tag, lo, hi, (hi - lo) > 10 ? "\n" : "");
    int i;
    for (i = lo; i <= hi; i++)
    {
        printf(" %2d", data[i]);
        if ((i - lo) % 10 == 9)
            putchar('\n');
    }
    if ((i - lo) % 10 != 0 || i == lo)
        putchar('\n');
}

static void check_sorted(int const *data, int lo, int hi)
{
    //printf("-->> check_sorted:\n");
    for (int i = lo; i < hi; i++)
    {
        if (data[i] > data[i+1])
            printf("Out of order: a[%d] = %d bigger than a[%d] = %d\n", i, data[i], i+1, data[i+1]);
    }
    //printf("<<-- check_sorted\n");
}

void Quick_Sort(int *a, int p, int r)
{
    if (p < r)
    {
        int q = partition(a, p, r);
        //dump_partition("Lo Range", a, p, q-1);
        //printf("Pivot: a[%d] = %d\n", q, a[q]);
        //dump_partition("Hi Range", a, q+1, r);
        Quick_Sort(a, p, q-1);          // JL: Optimization
        Quick_Sort(a, q+1, r);
    }
}

static int partition(int *a, int p, int r)
{
    assert(p <= r);
    if (p == r)                         // JL: Key change
        return p;                       // JL: Key change
    int i = p;                          // JL: Key change
    int j = r + 1;
    int x = a[p];
    //printf("-->> partition: lo = %d, hi = %d, pivot = %d\n", p, r, x);
    while (1)
    {
        do
        {
            j--;
            //printf("---- partition 1: a[%d] = %d\n", j, a[j]);
        }   while (x < a[j]);           // JL: Key change

        do
        {
            i++;
            //printf("---- partition 2: a[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i]);
        }   while (i <= r && x > a[i]); // JL: Key change

        if (i <= j)                     // JL: Key change
        {
            //printf("---- partition: swap a[%d] = %d with a[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i], j, a[j]);
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            // This swap step is crucial.
            int temp = a[p];            // JL: Key change
            a[p] = a[j];                // JL: Key change
            a[j] = temp;                // JL: Key change
            //dump_partition("a-lo", a, p, j-1);
            //printf("a-pivot[%d] = %d\n", j, a[j]);
            //dump_partition("a-hi", a, j+1, r);
            //printf("<<-- partition: return j = %d; a[%d] = %d; (i = %d; a[%d] = %d)\n", j, j, a[j], i, i, a[i]);
            return j;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Extended Sample Input

```
10

2 1 2 1
3 3 2 0 1
4 5 4 3 2 4
4 3 1 9 3 8
5 3 4 1 9 3 8
9 3 6 4 9 5 1 9 3 3 8
10 3 6 4 9 6 5 1 9 3 3 8

16
3 6 4 9 6 5 1 9 3 3
8 2 1 7 3 5
3

26
3 6 4 9 6 5 1 9 3 3
2 7 8 2 0 8 4 4 7 5
8 2 1 7 3 5
7

96
3 6 4 9 6 5 1 9 3 3
4 0 5 0 7 5 6 3 6 0
1 2 0 7 3 1 7 6 2 3
0 4 6 6 9 8 9 5 3 4
1 9 2 9 2 7 5 9 8 9
4 7 5 8 7 8 5 8 2 7
5 8 2 9 8 3 7 6 5 3
9 1 2 0 3 4 6 5 1 0
2 7 8 2 0 8 4 4 7 5
8 2 1 7 3 5
6
```

#### Extended Sample Output

```
Data set 0:
Before: [0..1]  1  2
After:  [0..1]  1  2
Found 1 at 1

Data set 1:
Before: [0..2]  3  2  0
After:  [0..2]  0  2  3
Missing 1

Data set 2:
Before: [0..3]  5  4  3  2
After:  [0..3]  2  3  4  5
Found 4 at 3

Data set 3:
Before: [0..3]  3  1  9  3
After:  [0..3]  1  3  3  9
Missing 8

Data set 4:
Before: [0..4]  3  4  1  9  3
After:  [0..4]  1  3  3  4  9
Missing 8

Data set 5:
Before: [0..8]  3  6  4  9  5  1  9  3  3
After:  [0..8]  1  3  3  3  4  5  6  9  9
Missing 8

Data set 6:
Before: [0..9]  3  6  4  9  6  5  1  9  3  3
After:  [0..9]  1  3  3  3  4  5  6  6  9  9
Missing 8

Data set 7:
Before: [0..15]
  3  6  4  9  6  5  1  9  3  3
  8  2  1  7  3  5
After:  [0..15]
  1  1  2  3  3  3  3  4  5  5
  6  6  7  8  9  9
Found 3 at 4

Data set 8:
Before: [0..25]
  3  6  4  9  6  5  1  9  3  3
  2  7  8  2  0  8  4  4  7  5
  8  2  1  7  3  5
After:  [0..25]
  0  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3  3
  4  4  4  5  5  5  6  6  7  7
  7  8  8  8  9  9
Found 7 at 19

Data set 9:
Before: [0..95]
  3  6  4  9  6  5  1  9  3  3
  4  0  5  0  7  5  6  3  6  0
  1  2  0  7  3  1  7  6  2  3
  0  4  6  6  9  8  9  5  3  4
  1  9  2  9  2  7  5  9  8  9
  4  7  5  8  7  8  5  8  2  7
  5  8  2  9  8  3  7  6  5  3
  9  1  2  0  3  4  6  5  1  0
  2  7  8  2  0  8  4  4  7  5
  8  2  1  7  3  5
After:  [0..95]
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  3
  3  3  3  3  3  3  4  4  4  4
  4  4  4  4  5  5  5  5  5  5
  5  5  5  5  5  5  6  6  6  6
  6  6  6  6  6  7  7  7  7  7
  7  7  7  7  7  7  8  8  8  8
  8  8  8  8  8  8  9  9  9  9
  9  9  9  9  9  9
Found 6 at 57
```

The code was also tested on some bigger data sets (2097 random entries, etc).  Automated check functions are crucial when the data is that big — hence `check_sorted()` and `check_consistency()`.  They check that the data is output in sorted order, and the conservation property, that all the values in the input appear in the output (as often as they appeared in the input).  Sorting is not supposed to add new data or remove pre-existing data.

Comment: A valiant attempt - doesn't begin to address the problem of the broken quicksort and associated seg faults, but there is a lot that a beginning programmer can learn here all the same.

Comment: @Floris: Time for work, sadly...you're right that I don't even attempt to address what's going on inside the QuickSort function or the partition function.  But being able to read and print data without crashing is an important first stage.  (Arguably, this should be posted as an answer to the other question.)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments the loop end test `*(array + i) != '\0'` for your print loop is an error.  `array` holds normal integers, and C does also consider `'\0'` to be an integer 0, as it considers all character literal values to be integers, and the comparison is legal, but since this is a (hopefully) sorted array of integers that may have any values (including negative values and 0) it could be that there are multiple 0s in some test data or more likely in this case, no 0s in your test data.  If you work out what this code would do in those cases then you should understand the error.