# segfault in merge sort implementation

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I'm working on a C implementation as an exercise (I'm a student). I have the logic fine (I've used the implementation itself before), but I get a segfault when actually running it. I've looked for a long time, and I can't understand what's causing it. Here is my complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ARRAY_CAPACITY 50

void do_sort(int* list); 
void merge_sort(int* list_of, int* buffer_of, int start, int end); 

void do_sort(int* list)
{
    int capacity = ((ARRAY_CAPACITY) / 2); 
    int buffer[capacity];
    merge_sort(list, buffer, 0, ARRAY_CAPACITY);   
}

void merge_sort(int* list_of, int* buffer_of, int start, int end)
{
    printf("%s", "hi!");
    int i, t; 
    if((end - start) < 2) return; 
    int mid = (start + end) / 2;

    merge_sort(list_of, buffer_of, start, mid); 
    merge_sort(list_of, buffer_of, mid, end);   

    int left = 0; 
    int right = mid; 

    for(i = 0; i < ARRAY_CAPACITY; i++)
    {
        buffer_of[i] = list_of[i]; 
    }

    for(t = start; t < end; t++)
    {
        if((left < (mid - start)) && (right == end || buffer_of[left] < list_of[right]))
        {
            list_of[t] = buffer_of[left];
            left++; 
        }

        else
        {
            list_of[t] = list_of[right]; 
            right++; 
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int number_array[ARRAY_CAPACITY]; 
    int i; 
    for(i = 0; i < ARRAY_CAPACITY; i++)
    {
        number_array[i] = (rand() % 100); 
    }
    printf("%d\n", number_array[3]); 

    int j, m;  

    printf("%s\n", "Pre-Sorted Array: "); 
    for(j = 0; j < ARRAY_CAPACITY; j++)
    {
        printf("%d ", number_array[j]); 
    }

    do_sort(number_array); 
    for(m = 0; m < ARRAY_CAPACITY; m++)
    {
        printf("%d ", number_array[m]); 
    } 
    printf("\n"); 
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
50 (this is a random number, but it always prints successfully)
Pre-Sorted Array: 
Segmentation fault
```

So the segfault triggers when I try to loop to print the pre sorted array, but I've just proven that the array values were properly set, so I can't fathom this error. Help?

Comment: Print a newline after you've finished printing the pre-sorted array; it makes the output appear.  When you're chasing a crash, make sure *every* diagnostic print ends with a newline so it will appear.

Comment: OK, so that does work, but it still segfaults immediately after, AKA when it calls do_sort (the little "hi!" printf in merge_sort doesn't even trigger).

Comment: Interesting...it isn't crashing for me on Mac OS X 10.9.  It isn't sorting properly either; it is losing all sorts of data and repeating all sorts of values.  Have you written code to check that the array is sorted, and also to check the conservation properties of a sort (each data item in the original must also appear in the output; no missing items, no extra items)?  It is also surprising you don't pass the number of items to be sorted into the top-level sort function.  It would be a lot easier to debug sorts of 1-10 items than sorts of 50 items.

Comment: OK, I'm using GCC. That's odd that it isn't sorting, either. I'll keep having a look at it.

Comment: Look at [Segmentation fault in Quicksort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727309/segmentation-fault-while-sorting/19729715#19729715) for usable examples of checking sort (conservation and order properties).  Not perfect, but workable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following code:

```
void merge_sort(int* list_of, int* buffer_of, int start, int end)
{
    ...
    for(i = 0; i < ARRAY_CAPACITY; i++)
    {
        buffer_of[i] = list_of[i]; 
    }
    ...
```

That code will get called, at one point, with the following arguments:

- `list_of` is an array of 50 integers.
- `buffer_of` is an array of 25 integers.
- `start` is 0.
- `end` is 50.

You will copy 50 elements of `list_of` into `buffer_of`, but `buffer_of` has only room for 25 elements.

Comment: This was it. I redid the copy using memcpy to make it cleaner, as well. Thanks for the catch. It would be something stupid that I took for granted like that.